# How to Constrain the slope to be positive in regression?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

How can I constrain my regression coefficient (only the slope, not the intercept) to be positive? It's a general statistical question, but specifically, I would like to have an r solution, and even more specifically when using model 2 regression (major axis regression).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and show us some code (plus example data) to show what you already tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do linear regression with [nls](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html), and limit the paramater range there.

**Example:** Using the `nl2sol` algorithm from the `Port` library we want to find a data set with `x` and `y` values with a negative Y-intercept and slope between 1.5 and 1.6:

```
nls(y~a+b*x,algorithm="port",start=c(a=0,b=1.5),lower=c(a=-Inf,b=1.4),upper=c(a=Inf,b=1.6))
```

This solution and others are explained in the more general question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61733/linear-regression-with-slope-constraint

Comment: Thanks!
And I figured that in order to deal with the major-axis-regression need of mine, I'll run the regression twice (first y~x, then x~y), average the slope of one regression with the reciprocal of the slope of the other regression. Finally, I'll fix this averaged slope as a constraint, and run the model for the third time to get the correct corresponding intercept.